# Copy attribute value of link to input value onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I want to copy the attribute value `val="ok"` of my link to an input field in my bootstrap modal :

```js
$('#link').on('click', function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("link").getAttribute("val");
  $("#mail").find(".compose").value = x;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mail" id="link" val="ok" class="btn btn-warning btn-flat" title="Mail"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Link</a>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="To:" class="compose" value="" />
```

Comment: `$("#mail").find(".compose").val(x);` or `$("#mail").find(".compose")[0].value = x;`

Comment: You should avoid creating your own attributes and use custom data attributes instead. Ex `data-val="ok"`. Also, you can't use the same attribute twice in any element `class="form-control" ... class="compose"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create custom data attribute `data-val` for example and then you can access it like `yourElem.dataset.val`

```js
var a = document.getElementById('link');
a.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var val = a.dataset.val;
  document.querySelector('.compose').value = val;
})
```

```html
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mail" id="link" data-val="ok" class="btn btn-warning btn-flat" title="Mail"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Link</a>
<input class="form-control compose" placeholder="To:" value="" />
```

You can also use JQuery use `data()`

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  $('input').val($(this).data('val'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mail" id="link" data-val="ok" class="btn btn-warning btn-flat" title="Mail"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Link</a>
<input class="form-control compose" placeholder="To:" value="" />
```

Comment: Thanks .. but how to make it work if the link is in looping ??

Comment: What do you mean by `link is in looping`, multiple links ?

Comment: There is 6 links, so I count it using javascript to make a for loop 

for(i = 0; i < countLink ; i++){
            $('#link').on('click', function() {
                $('#compose').val($('#link'+i+'').attr('val'+i+''));
            });
        }

but it doesn't work